# How to make string comparisons case insensitive?

Tags: case

I have the following code:

```
print("Now we need to get to know a little about you. What's your name?")
name=input()
print("Ok",name+", are you male, female, or another gender?")
gender=input()
if gender.lower==male.lower:
    print("So you're a man. Great!")
elif gender.lower==female.lower:
    print("So you're a woman. Great!")
else:
    print("Sorry I don't understand. We wont refer to your gender.")
    gender="unknown"
time.sleep(2)
```

As you can see, i've tried to whole "gender.lower" thing, but still if i type in "Male" I get an undefined gender. Help me out? Thanks

Comment: Which language is this? Please tag the question with the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses, since lower is a method. Try `gender.lower()` and `male.lower()` instead.

Using lower without parentheses refers to the built-in method, but does not invoke it. If you print `gender.lower` by itself in the interpreter, you'll see a reference to the method for the gender object. Printing `male.lower` gives a similar reference for a different object (the memory location in the printout will be different). Because these aren't identical, the conditional fails.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
 "male"
```

which is the word male, instead of

```
  male.lower
```

which is an undefined value that tries to call a function

Answer (score 0):

mayby it's better something like this:

```
if gender.lower=="male":
    print("So you're a man. Great!")
elif gender.lower=="female":
    print("So you're a woman. Great!")
```

I can't see that you defined a variable Male or Female